# Benefits And Tax Deduction For First Home In NSW Australia

Tags: taxes, australia, first-time-home-buyer

Hi I purchased a house for which the settlement was on 01/07/2016. Just wondering any benefits or tax benefits I can claim for the period until 30/06/2016. I'm aware of the First Home Owner Grant (FHOG). However, my house is an established one and its purchased value was more than $660k. I'm not an tax accountant so just want some more information or clues I can start with.

Answer (score 1):

hope you have gone through the nsw government websites regarding this:
http://www.osr.nsw.gov.au/grants/complete/fhog

According to the link - no grants for established homes. When did you move to NSW? here in ACT - we can claim the stamp duty in tax (within one year of moving here).

Comment: I know it's not for established home. Can we claim tax return on stamp duty in nsw too?